# What is the intuition to believe that a properly designed option can be dynamically hedged (just for the 1 stock case)?

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, quants, market-model, hedge

I would always presume that the portfolio consists of 1 stock and 1 risk-free asset. And that the $r, \alpha,\sigma$ are all non-zero, but might be time-dependent. When I say "any" option, I am actually referring to an option of the above type.

I understand that "any" European option can be perfectly dynamically hedged. In the discrete-time case, you can solve for the coefficients of each part of the portfolio backwards. Since this can be done in the discrete-time case, intuitively I believe that this can also be done in the continuous-time case.

But when I look at some type of option whose payoff depends on the stock price in the past in an arbitrary way (e.g. some option that is even more complicated than exotic option/American option), I can't find any intuition to convince myself that this option can be perfectly dynamically hedged, even in the discrete-time case.

In Chapter 5 of Steven E. Shreve's book "Stochastic Calculus for Finance 2 Continuous-Time Models",  he defines a complete market as a market where every derivate security can be hedged. It looks like that the existence of such a  definition has an implication that "a properly designed option can be dynamically hedged". I wonder where is the intuition from?

Comment: My intuition is that if you can compute a delta function that is $C^0$ then you can hedge it. Problems would arise when there is a discontinuity or when Delta is undefined.

Comment: @noob2 Do you mean you compute the Delta function from the option price in market?

Comment: No, I mean to derive it analytically from the model assumptions.

Comment: @noob2 But to derive a perfect option price you need to have a perfect hedging rule. To have a hedging rule you first need to have a faith that it can be hedged...

Comment: As long as your market model is *complete* you can always hedge an option. In that case all latent risks can indeed be neutralised by trading in either a specific instrument or a specific combination of them. Are you familiar with the concept of *state prices*?

Comment: Have a look here as well: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2692/why-a-self-financing-replicating-portfolio-should-always-exist

Comment: @Quantuple My question is essentially "why a complete market exists". The second fundamental theorem of asset pricing says that the model is complete if and only if the risk-neutral probability measure is unique. But in my understanding, the existence of risk-neutral measure only guarantees that any European option can be hedged. How do I convince myself that such a measure also guarantees that any American option, or even more complicated options, can be hedged?

Comment: @Quantuple Like I said in my post, an European option is a simple case since we can assume its price only relies on the current stock price and time. But  can we make such assumption for every option? Mathematically, the payoff of a option can be a function of the complete path of the price of the stock in the past. The biggest simplicity of European option is that its payoff is just a function of the endpoint of the complete path of the price of the stock.

Comment: @noob2 How do you compute the price of a general option?

Comment: @Ethan your understanding is wrong, especially the link between the existence of a risk neutral measure and European-style derivatives. Have a look at Mark Joshi's excellent books, for instance here: https://books.google.be/books?id=hAT9wO3bzt0C&pg=PA156&lpg=PA156&dq=completeness+joshi&source=bl&ots=TaaLUkyuzh&sig=lGI-5oGeKDXOpFLe7ZelTZnJ29Q&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj5wq-CvYzQAhVLXBoKHd87CRwQ6AEIIDAB#v=onepage&q=completeness%20joshi&f=false

Comment: The intuition is that a contingent claim is always a function of$t$ and  (at least) $S_t$, so provide $S_t$ is tradable it should always be possible to dynamically replicate the contingent claim. This argument leads to the famous BS pricing PDE in the BS market model. If you price more complicated claims, either a new state variable kicks in (ie the average for an Asian option) or its characteristics appear as boundary/terminal conditions of the exact same pricing PDE.

Comment: The key is that any self-financing portfolio should be a martingale under the risk-neutral measure when expressed wrt to a zero coupon bond numéraire should the market model be complete and in the absence of arbitrage. You can then price **any option** (multi-asset, path-dependent, with/without call features) as a discounted expectation by simulating underlying paths and using Monte Carlo, or equivalently (see Feynmann-Kac theorem) using PDEs (but this is not always practical). The pricing PDE is directly stems from the dynamic replciation argument.t

Comment: @Ethan I don't know any math, but I would try to find out how the price changes in response to small increments in various "things" (what Quantuple calls state variables) and hope that there are securities traded that correspond to all those "things".

Comment: @Quantuple "**The intuition is that a contingent claim is always a function of $t$ and (at least) $S_t$**" ---- I don't agree with this. But as you have mentioned, some other variables may kick in depending on the claims. But the situation can be very complicated and beyond what you just described. So how do you analyze an option that is beyond this scope?

Comment: Please read the links provided and think about the latest comment of @noob2.